# Align right in TableLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment, tablelayout

I still didn't find a solution how to do that in XML
I want my textview to be align to the left, and my imageview to be align to the right, here is the code:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tr1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Vibration"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />


</TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Is there any way to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `TableRow` to the following:

```
<TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tr1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:text="Vibration"
        android:gravity="left" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: put a color background to your TextView and ImageView, make sure they span across the whole width of the table

Comment: I found a solution, there has to be a paremeter "stretchcolumns" in tablelayout

Answer (score 1):

I achieved it by using,

```
android:gravity="left"
android:paddingLeft="50dp"
```

Hope it help!

Answer (score 0):

shouldnt it be:

android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  /// for the textbox

android:layout_alignParentRight="true" /// for the imageview . Try this

Answer (score 0):

I modified your layout, and this code works for me, hope this  would also work for you.

```
 <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

 <TableRow
android:id="@+id/tr1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>

    <TextView
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="Vibration"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="70" />


     <ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"        
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:contentDescription="contentDescription"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />  


 </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
```